# Как эффективно и быстро реализовать такую задачу?

Tags: java, алгоритм

подскажите пожалуйста, как лучше (быстрее, эффективнее) всего решить эту задачу:

У меня есть таблица, в ней находятся точки, справа от таблицы рисунок (изолинии), построенные по этим точкам, мне нужно, чтобы при выделении какой-либо точки в таблице, в рисунке (Java Graphics) выделялась данная точка.

Не хочется, каждую выделенную точку смотреть в массиве и потом выделять - а это перерисовка всего рисунка, может есть что по лучше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Таблицу с данными и информацию о выделенных значениях в таблице сделать моделью представления, модель представления передается в класс или функцию отвечающую за отрисовку изображения по модели, когда в модели происходят изменения выполнять полную перерисовку. Это не алгоритм, это стандартный подход.

Comment: Я подумал, может можно будет как-то без перерисовки

Comment: Обычный подход который используют везде, от веба до игр.  Можно оптимизировать функцию отрисовки, например разбить на две фазы, отрисовку изолиний и отрисовку точек, поместить их в отдельные функции. Все отрисовки выполнять во вне экранные изображения, если в фазе отрисовки изолиний в модели не было изменений, то возвращать последнее изображение. Если в модели появились изменения в выделенных точках, то перерисовать все точки. На последней фазе выполнить композинг - последовательно наложить изображения друг на друга.

Comment: отлично, то что нужно, спасибо!